# How to fix the event delay

Tags: c#, event-handling, hover

I'm making a table reservation system for a school project, and I'm using a list of PictureBoxes to represent the tables.
To these PictureBoxes I have linked a hover event, and when I hover the BackColor property is changed.

```
List<PictureBox> pb = new List<PictureBox> { pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3};

foreach (PictureBox p in pb)
{
    p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    p.BackColor = Color.White;
    p.MouseHover += new EventHandler(mouseOn);
}

private void mouseOn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((PictureBox)sender).BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

Everything works great, except that when I hover the mouse over, it takes 1 second before the event is triggerd, is there any way to trigger the event immidiately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to trigger event immediately, use `MouseEnter` event instead. By design your mouse should stay stationary for some time for `MouseHover` event to fire.

*BTW* `SystemInformation.MouseHoverTime` holds that delay for `MouseHover` event.

Answer (score 1):

> everything works great, except that when i haver the mouse over, it takes 1 second before the event is triggered

That's how [`Control.MouseHover`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover.aspx) is defined:

> Occurs when the mouse pointer rests on the control.

The "rests" part is the delay of a second. I don't know of any way of adjusting the length of time that the mouse has to rest of a control before it counts as a hover.

If you don't want any delay - i.e. you want an event which is raised as soon as the mouse enters the region of the control - you should be using [`Control.MouseEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter.aspx) instead.

From the documentation of both events:

> Mouse events occur in the following order:
>
> - MouseEnter
> - MouseMove
> - MouseHover / MouseDown / MouseWheel
> - MouseUp
> - MouseLeave