# Add_MouseHover() without delay

Tags: winforms, powershell, mouseevent, delay, mousehover

Is there a way to use .Add_MouseHover() without delay? As I understand it, this is a system delay that can be set in the registry. However, I want to use it in my script without delay when hovering over an element. Until now, I have been using such a solution:

```
$A = $False
$B.Add_MouseMove( if (!$A) { $Global:A = $True; ... A script to save the world from gladioli ... } )
```

But of course this is not a serious decision, since resources are spent on moving around the element. Please share your professional decisions on how to get zero delay when hover over an element. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix the event delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554128/how-to-fix-the-event-delay) or [Can the hover interval be changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10340093/150605)

Comment: Zero delay on hover basically means handling `Enter` event as is described in the first linked post. If you want to increase or decrease the `Hover` delay, take a look at the second linked post and just in case you wonder how you can apply that C# answer into your PowerShell code, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59043639/3110834) for example.